Google Console Error: You must complete the advertising ID declaration before you can release an app that targets Android 13 (API 33)
I'm trying to release a new version of my Flutter app on the play store (which does have ads in it), and I receive the following warning:

Your advertising ID declaration in Play Console says that your app uses advertising ID. A manifest file in one of your active artifacts doesn't include the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission.


If you don't include this permission in your manifest file, your advertising identifier will be zeroed out. This may break your advertising and analytics use cases, and cause loss of revenue. Learn more


You can remove these errors by updating your advertising ID declaration
Apps that target Android 13 (API 33) without the AD_ID permission will have their advertising identifier zeroed out. This may impact advertising and analytics use-cases. Learn more

To be perfectly clear:

I did include this permission in my manifest file
On google console, I went into: App Content => Actioned => Advertising ID => Manage => completed everything they asked of me => published a new release which was later approved

and yet, it's still giving me the same error!



I looked around for solutions, did everything that was suggested to no avail!
Would greatly appreciate any insight!


Fraud prevention, security, and compliance. this option is not related to advertising. Maybe you need to select Advertising or marketing Options.

Good point. They only reason I have it ticked is because someone suggested it in another post, and I forgot it was on
